# parameter C. epsilon as vector in kernlab's ksvm in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, kernlab

I am trying to use ksvm function of kernlab package in R for epsilon-SVM regression. I want to put parameters C(regularization constant) and epsilon (insensitivity) as vectors(length of vector = training data length). But I am not able to figure out how to do this. Please suggest some way.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you assume that you can do it? According to [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/kernlab.pdf) of `ksvm` you can only weight classes, not particular samples. Such modification is accessible in for example [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) python library (as samples' weights).

To artificialy implement per samples C-weights you could oversample your data. It will be very inefficient (especially if you have large differences in C values), but it can be applied to almost any SVM library.